# Click button by JavaScript after popup appears

Tags: javascript

On the website, there's a button after which you click, there appears a new popup that also has a button. What I am trying to achieve is that by JavaScript, I want to click the first button and when pop-up appears, I want to click on that another button.

Code:

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("firstButtonClassName");

for (var i = 1, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
   arr[i].click();
   console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("popupButtonClassName"))
}
```

With the above code, first button is clicked fine and popup appears, but as you can see, console log above prints empty array instead of the array that contains popup's button..

Is there some trick I don't understand ?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example of the issue ?

Comment: can you update the whole code or example

Comment: Is the class name correct?

Comment: Your iteration starts with 1, so arr[1] will be the second button of the "firstButtonClassName", the first one will not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it by using click event in javascript
for example :

```
<button onclick="alert('hi')">Alert Me </button>
```